# options are not getting printed/echoed?

Tags: php

This page generates the option pulled from database . another page brings here the year of joining of students via year_joining . rest of the mysql queries works absolutely fine ( tested )

```
<?php
include_once("../Include/connectdb.php");

if($_GET['year_join'])
{
$id=$_GET['year_join'];

$result1 = mysql_query("select distinct sub_id from subject_profile where   batch='$id'        

")or die(mysql_error());

  while($subid = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){

 $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM  `subjects` WHERE  `sub_id` LIKE    

'$subid[sub_id]'");

    $subject=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);

    if($subject[name]!=""){
  //print "<OPTION value=".$tmp.'">'.$tmp.'</OPTION>';
  //print "<OPTION value='$tmp'>'$tmp'</OPTION>";
  echo "<option value=".$subject['name'] . '">' . $subject['name'] . '</option>';
  //echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
 //}
 }
}
}
?>
```

FYI :

```
//print "<OPTION value=".$tmp.'">'.$tmp.'</OPTION>';
//print "<OPTION value='$tmp'>'$tmp'</OPTION>";
echo "<option value=".$subject['name'] . '">' . $subject['name'] . '</option>';
//echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
```

none of these are working ... :(

with simple echo $tmp it works 
but when ever i put as

```
echo "<option value=";
```

the result is blank page ...

and when i am echo - ing just the variable its works perfectly fine

```
echo $tmp;
```

gives the list of all the subjects ..

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: what is the alternative ?? for mysql_*

Comment: The alternative for `mysql_` is [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), or use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Your HTML code is inconsistent. Use 'option'. Lowercase is the way to go

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff mysqli:: works also

Comment: @ColeJohnson - Yes, I know that. It is just easier to use `mysqli` the same way as `mysql` if you are new to `mysqli`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the problem regarding "not displaying output", I believe you have missed a `<select>` tag enclosing the `<option>` tags.

As a side note, in the query, change it like this:

```
"SELECT name FROM  `subjects` WHERE  `sub_id` LIKE '{$subid[sub_id]}'"
```

or,

```
"SELECT name FROM  `subjects` WHERE  `sub_id` LIKE '" . $subid[sub_id] . "'"
```

Still it is not safe. You should escape the values and better use a prepared statement using mysqli or PDO

Comment: you dont get it .. the problem is with echo statement , the sql queries works absolutely fine ...

Comment: Do you have a `<SELECT>` tag surrounding the options ? Have you checked the html source of the outputted page?

Comment: @ratankumar - Here is how to escape the values: [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: You are welcome :) Also, the syntax for an option would be like this: `<option value="abc">abc</option>`. That is, the value attribute is enclosed in double quotes. So, that mistake is also there in your code. Check Shaquin Trifonoff's answer for the sample.

Comment: Yeah that function helps in escaping the values and prevents sql injection. But we all recommend using `mysqli` or `PDO`. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is as per Akhilesh B Chandran's answer, with a missing `<select>` tag.

Other than that, there will be a problem when `$subject['name']` has a space in it.

The problem is this line:

```
echo "<option value=".$subject['name'] . '">' . $subject['name'] . '</option>';
```

It should be like this:

```
echo '<option value="'.$subject['name'] . '">' . $subject['name'] . '</option>';
```

In what you currently have, the browser interprets the result as this:

```
<option value=insert name here">insert name here</option>
```

As it is visible, there is a missing quote after `value=`.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes don't match up, which is why PHP is failing.

Try changing:

```
echo "<option value=".$subject['name'] . '">' . $subject['name'] . '</option>';
```

to:

```
echo "<option value=".$subject['name'] . ">" . $subject['name'] . "</option>";
```

Basically, you start off using a `"`, and switch partway through to using `'`